# GPS location for IoT central map tile

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

I am trying to get my IoT Central app to show the GPS location using a map tile. My JSON file sends over the location and i have this tied to the map tile but the map tile keeps saying "Waiting for data" I have tried everything to get this to show and i can't seem to get it to work.

I have followed the JSON layout as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-telemetry-properties-commands)

You can see the raw data tab below which shows the data coming in and that it is associating the data with the gps  capability but the map shows nothing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKmLi.png)

Comment: Seems like it should work, could you try creating a simulated device in IoT Central and see if that gets displayed correctly? And if you add to the view your temperature reading, does that get updated or does it also show "Waiting for data"?

Comment: I will try and add a simulated device, the temp graph shows as expected, I've also used the azure cli and the data matches the requirements.

Comment: If the simulated device works, try reprovisioning your other device (delete, create). Otherwise, it's probably a bug and you can report it through the Q&A site (as you did)

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a quick test and it looks like everything is working well:

1. New App with a custom device template
   [image]
2. Creating a View
   [image]
3. Exporting a device template for my [tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester) (simulator):

   ```
    {
      "@id": "urn:custom6ec42lhnjx:gps38u:1",
      "@type": "CapabilityModel",
      "contents": [],
      "displayName": {
        "en": "gps"
      },
       "implements": [
        {
      "@type": "InterfaceInstance",
      "displayName": {
        "en": "Interface"
      },
      "name": "gpsea",
      "schema": {
        "@id": "urn:custom6ec42lhnjx:gpsea:1",
        "@type": "Interface",
        "contents": [
          {
            "@type": [
              "Telemetry",
              "SemanticType/Location"
            ],
            "displayName": {
              "en": "gps"
            },
            "name": "gps",
            "schema": "geopoint"
          },
          {
            "@type": [
              "Telemetry",
              "SemanticType/Temperature"
            ],
            "displayName": {
              "en": "temp"
            },
            "name": "temp",
            "schema": "double"
              }
            ],
            "displayName": {
              "en": "Interface"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "@context": [
        "http://azureiot.com/v1/contexts/IoTModel.json"
      ]
    }
   ```
4. Provisioning and Simulating device (with a random values):

[image]

5. Dashboard IoT Central App:

[image]

6. Example with simulating your telemetry data:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, unfortunately only by starting again and deleting everything i had done thus far, as soon as i recreated my IoTC app and reimplemented the function that deals with the webhook everything worked perfectly. Still strange as the data format and everything else remained unchanged. But thank you for your help.